# compare only time vlaue from textbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am taking three text boxes. time in text boxes are not to be same. means 1st text box value is 2013-10-01 12:00 date time.and second is 2013-10-01 12:00 and third also 2013-10-12 12:00.but actual problem is that when date are diff-rent then same time should be allow.when date and time are same so it should through error message or alert message to user.please help me to solve this.

```
function validate Form()
{

var a=document.get Element By Id("mybox1"). value;
var b=document.get Element By Id("mybox2"). value;
var c=document.get Element By Id("mybox3"). value;

var a_time = a.replace(/ /g,''). sub st r (a.replace(/ /g,''). length - 5);
var b_time = b.replace(/ /g,''). sub st r (b.replace(/ /g,''). length - 5);
var c_time = c.replace(/ /g,''). sub st r (c.replace(/ /g,''). length - 5);

if (a=="" &&  b=="" && c=="")
  {
  alert("Please select at least one date and time !");
  return false;
  }
else if (a_time === b_time)  
  {
  alert("Please select diff-rent time!");
  return false;
  }
else if (a_time === c_time)
  {
  alert("Please select diff-rent time!");
  return false;
  }
  else
  {
      return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: substr() is not problem and getelementbyid is not problem.

Comment: Why do you put the spaces in substr and getElementById?

Comment: thats not the actual problem i can write code substr properly

Comment: No doubt, but why did you put the spaces there in this question?

Comment: i want to post the code but it show problem in posting so i enter spaces.but solve my actual problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... only need to compare date too...

```
if (a=="" &&  b=="" && c=="")
        {
            alert("Please select at least one date and time !");
            return false;
        }
        else if (a_time === b_time && a===b)  
        {
            alert("Please select diff-rent time!");
            return false;
        }
        else if (a_time === c_time && a===c)
        {
            alert("Please select diff-rent time!");
            return false;
        }
```